# Unexpected empty result set using limit with order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with millions of records and I've been running this query once a day for over 500 days and just recently it stopped working.

The query looks as follows:

```
SELECT id FROM table
ORDER BY column1 desc, column2 desc, column3 desc
LIMIT 522, 1
```

This returns an empty result set.  However, if I change the limit to anything less than 500 it works fine.

If I remove the limit and do a COUNT(id) with the order by, it returns a count of the multi-million row table.

Comment: Perhaps you have fewer than 522 rows

Comment: doing a select count as mentioned returns a number over 1 million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly how it occurred, but after optimizing the table it began working again...

Comment: Optimizing as in ?  indexing columns ?

Answer (score 1):

I can only imagine some sort of time-out or error occurring.  The `order by` and `limit` should be returning rows, if they are there.

First, check to see if you are getting an error.  If you are calling from an application, this requires checking the error status.

For a time-out, you might consider adding an index on `table(column1 desc, column2 desc, column3 desc, id)`.  This should radically improve the performance of the query.

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to diagnose these issues remotely and very often you can find more info in MySQL logs -- these are very helpful diagnosing abnormal behavior.

Also, try running your query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM
(SELECT id FROM table
ORDER BY column1 desc, column2 desc, column3 desc) r
LIMIT 522, 1
```